# OSLog Logger doesn't work on XCode Playground: Couldn't lookup symbols: ___dso_handle

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground, oslog

I want to test new iOS 14 `Logger` in Playground but I found next issue:

```swift
// MyLog.playground

import os

let logger = Logger()
logger.log("Hello OSLog")
```

Outputs:

```
error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
  ___dso_handle
  ___dso_handle
```

The same I have with old OSLog API:

```
os_log("Hello OSLog")
```

Is it possible to use `OSLog` with playgrounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a workaround to work with `Logger` on Playgrounds. You should make new file inside your playground (e.g. Sources/Log.swift) and implement code there:

```swift
// Log.swift

import os

let logger = Logger()

public func log(_ text: String) {
    logger.log("\(text)")
}
```

```swift
// MyLog.playground

log("Hello OSLog")
```

Comment: @zeytin Old versions of what OSLog / XCode?

Comment: yeap what is difference now ?